# Why jquery option is not working when pass value using wp_localize_script?

Tags: plugins, jquery

0 down vote favorite

I am developing a wordpress plugin and i am facing a problem when pass value to jquery using wp_localize_script . This is my code

```
function newsbox_load_custom_script() {

$newsbox_parameters = array(
  'newsPerPage' => 4 ,
  'newsTickerInterval' => 2500
);
wp_enqueue_script('newsbox-custom-script', plugins_url( '/scripts/custom.js', __FILE__ ),'', '1.0.1', true);
wp_localize_script('newsbox-custom-script', 'newsbox_parameters',$newsbox_parameters);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'newsbox_load_custom_script');
```

and this is jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery(".news_list").bootstrapNews({
     newsPerPage: newsbox_parameters.newsPerPage,
     autoplay: true,
     pauseOnHover: true,
     navigation: false,
     direction: 'down',
     newsTickerInterval: newsbox_parameters.newsTickerInterval,
     onToDo: function () {
        //console.log(this);
     }
  });
});
```

If i write jquery like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery(".news_list").bootstrapNews({
     newsPerPage: 4,
     autoplay: true,
     pauseOnHover: true,
     navigation: false,
     direction: 'down',
     newsTickerInterval: 2500,
     onToDo: function () {
        //console.log(this);
     }
  });
});
```

Then it work perfectly. http://digitalsensebd.com/newsbox/

But if i pass value using wp_localize_script, it is not working http://digitalsensebd.com/newsbox_plugin/?page_id=4

Please tell me the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that the values aren't the correct "type". Meaning you might be passing string values when the script expects integers, so try converting the values to integers first.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  var newsPerPage = parseInt( newsbox_parameters.newsPerPage );
  var newsTickerInterval = parseInt( newsbox_parameters.newsTickerInterval );

  jQuery(".news_list").bootstrapNews({
     newsPerPage: newsPerPage,
     autoplay: true,
     pauseOnHover: true,
     navigation: false,
     direction: 'down',
     newsTickerInterval: newsTickerInterval,
     onToDo: function () {
        //console.log(this);
     }
  });
});
```